# AngularJS Directive not reading data from controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to learn about angular Directives and following the example given in here (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), have written the below code. Could anyone please guide me as what am i doing wrong that the data from the scope of the controller is not being read in the directive? The site says nothing about it! And there is no error upon executing the code, it just does not display any data. Please help.

```
           //My Html
           <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html data-ng-app="MyApp">
          <head>
          <title>Angular Directives</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          </head>
         <body >
         <div data-ng-controller = "MyCtrl"></div>
         <div data-template-expanding-directive></div>

         <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="js/templateExpandingDirective.js"></script>
         </body>
         </html>

           //My JS
           'use strict';

           var myapp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

           myapp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
               $scope.customer = {
                    name: "Jenny",
                    place: "England"
                };  
                  }])
                 .directive('templateExpandingDirective',function(){
                       return {
                   template: 'Name: {{customer.name}}' 
                    };
                 });
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive is currently out of controller scope. So you need to have directive inside the controller scope. The html should be like this -

```
 <div data-ng-controller = "MyCtrl">
         <div data-template-expanding-directive></div>
 </div>
```

If you do not move the directive element inside the controller div element then you can either have one more parent 'div' element or access the data from global root scope.